# Image of singular chain map, on $S^1$

Tags: functions, algebraic-topology

*First note that the question is very elemantary we need to find just a continuous function satisfying basic property.*

**Definitions:**

$$\triangle^n=\{(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})\;|\; x_0+x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1}=1\}$$

For $S^1$ as a topological space we are defining chain complex as

$$C_n(S^1)=FA\left(\{f:\triangle^n\to S^1| f \quad\text{is continuous}\}\right)$$

where $FA$ means free abelian group generated by input.

Considering this particular chain complex of $S^1$

$$\cdots\xrightarrow{d_{n+2}} C_{n+1}(S^1)\xrightarrow{d_{n+1}} C_n(S^1)\xrightarrow{d_{n}} C_{n-1}(S^1)\xrightarrow{d_{n-1}}\cdots$$

Where $d_n:C_n(S^1)\to C_{n-1}(S^1)$ defined on generator as:
$\sigma\in C_n(S^1)$
$$d_n(\sigma)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j \sigma\circ \varphi_j$$
where $$\varphi_j:\triangle^{n-1}\to\triangle^n\\ (x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})\mapsto (x_0,x_1,\cdots,\underbrace{0}_{\text{ith place}},\cdots,x_{n-1})$$

**Question:**

Let $$\sigma :\triangle^1 \to S^1\\ (x_0,x_1)\mapsto e^{2\pi i x_1}$$

and for fixed $n\in\mathbb Z$ $$f:S^1\to S^1\\ z\mapsto z^n$$

We can show easily that $\sigma\in C_1(S^1)$ and $f\circ\sigma\in C_1(S^1)$ are $1-$cycles meaning they are in $ker(d_1:C_1(S^1)\to C_0(S^1))$

Question: Are $f\circ \sigma$ and $n.\sigma$ same in $H_1(S^1)=\dfrac{ker(d_1)}{Im(d_{2})}$ equivalently is there some continuous function $\eta:\triangle^2\to S^1$( $\eta\in C_2(S^1)$), such that $d_2(\eta)=n.\sigma-f\circ\sigma$  (or we can separately show there are two functions that has images $f\circ \sigma$ and $n.\sigma$)

So let us try to construct desired functions:
$$\eta:\triangle^2\to S^1$$
It should satisfy the $d_2$ so given $(x_0,x_1)\in\triangle ^1$

$$d_2(\eta)(x_0,x_1)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^2(-1)^j \eta\circ \varphi_j(x_0,x_1)\\=\eta\circ \varphi_0(x_0,x_1)-\eta\circ \varphi_1(x_0,x_1)+\eta\circ \varphi_2(x_0,x_1)\\ =\eta(0,x_0,x_1)-\eta(x_0,0,x_1)+ \eta(x_0,x_1,0)$$

I tried to use $(x_0,x_1,x_2)\mapsto e^{2\pi i x_0}\\ (x_0,x_1,x_2)\mapsto e^{2\pi i x_0(x_1+x_2)}$

but in each conditions I find $d_n(\eta)=1$

I feel  like constructing something like that a bit hard, maybe I cannot see it, can you please give me hint or how to show existence implicitly without finding $\eta$ explicitly.

Comment: What is $n.\sigma$?

Comment: $n$ is an integer and $\sigma$ is a generator of a free abelian group so we can multiply

Comment: You can use "cdot" then.

Comment: And the answer is "yes"
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4292249/degree-of-a-map-on-the-circle-via-homology-definition/4292256#4292256

Comment: yes projection is  perfect.